# i need help making a status bar label

Tags: javascript, status, label

I need to make a labeled button that checks all the previous boxes I have above it and then reports back whether they are valid or not by putting the status on the screen after the button without popping up an alert, I am doing this in JavaScript so any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction(x){
                x.style.background="yellow";
            }

            function validateForm(){
                var Fid=document.getElementById("firstName").value;
                if (Fid.length < 3) {
                    alert("first id is not valid");
                    return;
                }
                var Lid=document.getElementById("lastName").value;
               if (Lid.length < 3) {
                   alert("Last id is not valid");
                   return;
               }

               var Age=document.getElementById("age").value;
               if (Age.length == 0) {
                   alert("Age is not valid");
                   return;
               }
           } //End validateForm()

           <script language="javascript">
               function checkEmail() {

                   var email = document.getElementById("email");
                   var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                   if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
                       alert("Please provide a valid email address");
                       email.focus;
                       return false;
                   }
               } 
           </script>
     </script>
 </head>
 <body>
       First id: <input type="text" id="firstName" onFocus="myFunction(this)"><br>
      Last id: <input type="text" id="lastName" onFocus="myFunction(this)"><br>
      Age: <input type="text" id="age" onFocus="myFunction(this)"><br>
      E-mail address: <input type="text" id="email" onFocus="myFunction(this)"><br>
     <label id="status">status</label><br>
     <button id="CheckButton" onClick="return validateForm();">Check Form</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of alerting, just set the `innerHTML` of your status label:

```
var Fid=document.getElementById("firstName").value;
if (Fid.length < 3) {
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.innerHTML = status.innerHTML + '<br>First id is not valid';
    //alert("first id is not valid");
    return;
}
```

Based on your comment, modify your HTML like so:

```
First id: <input type="text" id="firstName" onFocus="myFunction(this)"><br>
Last id: <input type="text" id="lastName" onFocus="myFunction(this)"><br>
Age: <input type="text" id="age" onFocus="myFunction(this)"><br>
E-mail address: <input type="text" id="email" onFocus="myFunction(this)"><br>
<span id="status">status</span><br>
<div id='firstNameDiv' style='display: none'>First id is not valid</div>
<div id='lastNameDiv' style='display: none'>Last is id not valid</div>
<div id='ageDiv' style='display: none'>Age is not valid</div>
<div id='emailDiv' style='display: none'>Email is not valid</div>
<button id="CheckButton" onClick="return validateForm();">Check Form</button>
```

And your javascript like this:

```
var Fid=document.getElementById("firstName").value;
if (Fid.length < 3) {
    document.getElementById('firstNameDiv').style.display = "";
}
else {
    document.getElementById('firstNameDiv').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: that really help alot now i just need it to remove the message when the field is filled an valid

Comment: @Myrmidon86 I'll modify my answer for something that should work with what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help coding is driving me up the wall lol

Comment: i've been asked to make an addition to it where it would state that all fields are valid when the proper inputs have been entered

Comment: @Myrmidon86 Add a new variable to track the validity of the fields. If any of the validations fail, set the value to false. Once it complete, you can examine the variable for true/false, and show/hide a different div.